# Explanation about RegionFunction and MeshFunctions?

Tags: plotting, options, mesh

In the link, [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html), consider the example(*Variation on the Spheres*) given in the *Neat Examples* section.

[image]

Can someone please explain how `RegionFunction` and `MeshFunctions` are working out there?

Comment: The index `i` is the Table[] index. Each element there is a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it can be found in documentation but I do not consider it basic since it involves couple of options.

From `Details` of [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionFunction.html) and [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeshFunctions.html) You can see that in case of `ParametricPlot3D` it can accept 5 arguments: `x, y, z, u, v` where `u` and `v` are in fact ϕ and θ.

**First example** is quite easy.

```
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, Sin[6 ϕ] Sin[6 θ] >= 1/4]
```

force *Mathematica* to plot only a region of surface which fulfils condition above.

**Second example:** `MeshFunctions` is an option for specifying functions *Mathematica* will be reffering to while creating `Mesh`. You can see that this function is the same as used in inequality inside `RegionFunction`.

```
MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, Sin[6 ϕ] Sin[6 θ]]}
```

From [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mesh.html) `Details` You can learn that You can set `Mesh` divisions for explicit values, absolute or reffered to our `MeshFunctions`.

Our `MeshFunctions` is **`f: [0, 2Pi]x[0, Pi] -> [-1, 1]`**.

So if We set **`Mesh -> {{1/4}}`** there will be only two regions on a surface, those for which

- `-1 < f[ϕ, θ] < 1/4` and
- `1/4 < f[ϕ, θ] < 1`

With **`MeshShading -> {Opacity[0.5], Green}`** You can set those regions styling. Notice that first one `Opacity[.5]` is indeed `White` but looks bluish because of default `Lighting` (check `Lighting->"Neutral"`).

So for 3 division values there are going to be 4 regions:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},
                 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, Sin[6 ϕ] Sin[6 θ]], 
                 Mesh -> {{-.9, 0, 1/4}}, PlotPoints -> 75, 
                 MeshShading -> {Yellow, Blue, Green, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great.  Thank You Kuba